# Lua: Function to Change Value in Dictionary

Tags: function, dictionary, lua

I want to create a function to change a value in Dictionary. I came up with something really complicated. It works, but it also adds additional output I can't explain.

```
boolValues = {
    firstBool=true,
    secondBool=true,
    thirdBool=true,
}

function setBoolValue(boolName, state)
    local newTable = {boolName, false,}
    for k, v in pairs(boolValues) do
        if k == boolName then
            v = state
        end
        newTable[k] = v
    end
    return newTable
end

function showTable(tableName)
    print("printing the table:")
    for k, v in pairs(tableName) do
        print(k,v)
    end
    print("")
end

showTable(boolValues)
boolValues = setBoolValue("secondBool", false)
showTable(boolValues)
```

The result:

```
printing the table:
firstBool   true
secondBool  true
thirdBool   true

printing the table:
1   secondBool
2   false
firstBool   true
secondBool  false
thirdBool   true
```

Where are the pairs "1 , secondBool" and "2, false" coming from? What is a better way to write a function to change a value in dictionary?

Comment: This should be considered a typo, according to my understanding, what you are looking for should be `local newTable = { [boolName] = false }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where are the pairs "1 , secondBool" and "2, false" coming from?

From here:

```lua
local newTable = {boolName, false,}
```

This is equivalent to

```lua
local newTable = {}
newTable[1] = boolName
newTable[2] = false
```

> What is a better way to write a function to change a value in dictionary?

If you want to mutate the table: Just `boolValues[boolName] = state`. No need for a function (note that due to proxy tables with `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods, this also isn't a problem if you decide that you need to hook this later on).

If you want to create a mutated copy, first copy, then mutate. A simple shallowcopy would be:

```lua
local function shallowcopy(t)
    local copy = {}
    for k, v in pairs(t) do copy[k] = v end
    return copy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the easy solution, I am doing it like this now, even though the function is not necessary:

```
function setBoolValue(boolName, state)
    boolValues[boolName] = state
end
```

Example:

```
setBoolValue("secondBool", false)
```